# Imap/Pop3 notification Android

Tags: java, android, imap, pop3

I have been working on an email client in Android. I am using javamail API for connecting the IMAP and POP3 accounts and they are working quite well. The email client may hold several accounts.

I just want to know a) how should I implement new mail notification which needs to show up to the user. b) Also what should I use to sync new emails?

Just need a right direction.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) from a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to show the notification and get the mails every x-minutes with a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Comment: i know how to notify. I just want to know how my app will get response from mail server that new mail has arrived

Comment: Use a http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html in the Service and get your mails every x-minutes.

Comment: If you're using IMAP, finding out if there is something new is part of the protocol, look at SUBSCRIBE as well.

Comment: @evertvandenbruel... If i use service and polling... should it not dry out the battery?